# How to selectively sync playlists from iCloud to iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-music

I am using Apple Music and all my purchased songs & the playlists are synced to the cloud. However, I don't want every single playlist from showing up on my iPhone when I turn on the iCloud music. Is there any way to choose which playlists shows up and which do not?

I know I can delete them from my iPhone but the songs will still show up in my library. Also, I don't know if deleting them from my iPhone will affect the sync in all my other devices.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable a playlist from **showing up** while still using iCloud Music Library.

You can, however, control which playlists are **downloaded** by clicking the (•••) and changing wether it keeps songs offline.